# jQuery mobile panel between header and footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile panel usually convers part of the page from top to bottom:

```
<div data-role="panel">...</div>
```

The demos page has left table of content panel that is limited between the header and the footer - not from top to bottom:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/intro/

How to limit the panel between the header and the footer?
How is it done in CSS?

Comment: there's a JS solution not a CSS one.

Comment: Just add this to your css file (.ui-panel-display-overlay {
z-index: 100; 
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to calculate height of *viewport*, *header* and *footer*. Subtract height of both toolbars from *viewport*'s height will give you the height of space between both toolbars. Also, push the panel down by overriding `top` style of the panel.

```
    /* active page */
var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
    /* viewport */
    screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
    /* header - whether it's fixed */
    header = $(".ui-header", activePage).hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight(),
    /* footer - whether it's fixed */
    footer = $(".ui-footer", activePage).hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight(),
    /* math 101 */
    panelheight = screen - header - footer;
/* update "min-height" and "top" */
$('#panelID').css({
    'top': header,
        'min-height': panelheight
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3Lqhov14/)**