# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 right panel animation

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, panel

I'm using a JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 external panel on the right side of some pages, and the pages have also the class ui-responsive-panel, so that the main content is resized according to the panel width to show its whole content.

The panel has also data-dismissible="false" because in the main content are some form controls and user interaction while the panel is open.

The panel shows itself through the "reveal" animation, which causes the page main content first to swipe off to the leftmost side of the page, and then resize to the remaining page width.

```
<div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="reveal" data-dismissible="false">
</div>
```

This is the CSS i'm use to customize the JQM right panel:

```
.ui-panel {
    width: 25em;
}
.ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-position-right {
    margin-left: 25em;
}
.ui-panel-page-content-position-right,
.ui-panel-dismiss-open.ui-panel-dismiss-position-right {
    left: 0;
    right: -25em;
}
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-page-content-position-right.ui-panel-page-content-display-reveal {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25em,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-25em,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-25em,0,0);
}
```

Is there a simply way to avoid the initial left swipe-off of the leftmost main part of the page, and instead to have the main content smoothly decrease its size *from the right side* during the panel animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below is a possible solution using the jQuery animate() method. Let say its enough to make only the page-content responsive, as the full-page animation (toolbars included) is not a requirement:

```
$(".ui-panel").on("panelbeforeopen", function (event, ui) {
    $(".ui-page-active .ui-content").animate({
        "margin-right": "50%"
    }, 300,"swing");
});

$(".ui-panel").on("panelbeforeclose", function (event, ui) {
    $(".ui-page-active .ui-content").animate({
        "margin-right": "0%"
    }, 300,"swing",function()
                    {
                        $(this).removeAttr("style");
                    });
});
```

Furthermore, when used with a Panel with *data-display="overlay"* the class "ui-responsive-panel" in the body is no longer necessary and can be dropped, because the Panel height can be easily adapted to fill only the page-content height (credits: [jQuery mobile panel between header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384730/jquery-mobile-panel-between-header-and-footer)) .

```
function scalePanelToContent() {
    var screenH = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var headerH = $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1;
    var footerH = $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1;
    var panelH = screenH - headerH - footerH;
    $(".ui-panel").css({
      "top": headerH,
      "bottom": footerH,
      "min-height": panelH
    });
}
```

By adding `"bottom": footerH` the Panel is nicely filling the full page-content height also when the browser window is resized.

Panel: the CSS Panel animation is adapted with a minimum of changes, using the same criteria that jQuery actually uses for transitions and animations support:

```
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

The final result from user-experience point of view, is very closely as using a Panel with data-display="push" or data-display="reveal" in a Panel responsive page: a nice smooth animation - moreover without the overhead of the panel wrapper on each JQM page and with the header and footer toolbars always available at full width without shrinking.

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6Cnn/38/